# How to unselect all checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have multiselect list box, I want to clear all selected items On clear button click.

```
<asp:ListBox id="StatusField" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="4" />
```

I tried as follows.

```
 $("#StatusField option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: Your code is for dropdown not checkbox

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript or Jquery to check and uncheck all checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730471/javascript-or-jquery-to-check-and-uncheck-all-checkbox)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to unselect a <select> in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1857781/995876)

Comment: I tried with that, It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
$("#[id$=StatusField ]").multiselect("uncheckAll");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how your code is for a dropdown and not a select box, you can try:

```
$('#StatusField :selected').attr('selected', '');
```

Comment: try passing in false instead of '', the false has no quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a dropdown can you try:

```
 $("#StatusField").val("");
```